# Non-zero exit status tidyverse install packages Rstudio

Tags: r, windows, tidyverse, install.packages, tidytext

I have been roaming the internet trying to find a solution, but haven't found it yet.

My problem is: i can't install tidytext. I also found out I can't re-install tidyverse for some reason.

The error code is:

```
install.packages("tidytext")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘ISOcodes’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘stopwords’


  There is a binary version available but the source
  version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
stopwords  0.9.0    1.0             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘stopwords’, ‘tidytext’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stopwords_1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 104532 bytes (102 KB)
downloaded 102 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidytext_0.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3088493 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

ERROR: dependency 'ISOcodes' is not available for package 'stopwords'
* removing 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/stopwords'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOUYnrR/downloaded_packages/stopwords_1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stopwords’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'stopwords' is not available for package 'tidytext'
* removing 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/tidytext'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOUYnrR/downloaded_packages/tidytext_0.2.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidytext’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOUYnrR\downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("tidyverse")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘vctrs’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘dplyr’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘purrr’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘xml2’


  There are binary versions available but the source
  versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
ellipsis    0.1.0  0.3.0              TRUE
vctrs       0.1.0  0.2.2              TRUE
dplyr     0.8.0.1  0.8.4              TRUE
haven       2.1.0  2.2.0              TRUE
hms         0.4.2  0.5.3             FALSE
purrr       0.3.2  0.3.3              TRUE
rlang       0.3.4  0.4.4              TRUE
tibble      2.1.1  2.1.3              TRUE
tidyr       0.8.3  1.0.2              TRUE
xml2        1.2.0  1.2.2              TRUE
tidyverse   1.2.1  1.3.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ellipsis_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 30847 bytes (30 KB)
downloaded 30 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/vctrs_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 499748 bytes (488 KB)
downloaded 488 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/dplyr_0.8.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3029353 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/haven_2.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 988500 bytes (965 KB)
downloaded 965 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/purrr_0.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 327437 bytes (319 KB)
downloaded 319 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tibble_2.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 238931 bytes (233 KB)
downloaded 233 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tidyr_0.8.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 907112 bytes (885 KB)
downloaded 885 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/xml2_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3543977 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘haven’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘purrr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6CSjp\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘hms’, ‘tidyverse’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150752 bytes (147 KB)
downloaded 147 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_0.5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 134669 bytes (131 KB)
downloaded 131 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB)
downloaded 696 KB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6CSjp/downloaded_packages/lifecycle_0.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'hms' ...
** package 'hms' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/hms'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/hms'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6CSjp/downloaded_packages/hms_0.5.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'tidyverse' ...
** package 'tidyverse' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'haven' 2.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 2.2.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/tidyverse'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/tidyverse'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6CSjp/downloaded_packages/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

I thought the issue was dependencies, but it's not in the error message/output.

Because of the Rtools warning, I have downloaded Rtools, which never was required before - but I get this:

```
> install.packages("Rtools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/maria/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

My R / system info: [Default] [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4
I work on a Microsoft computer.

Hope someone knows what's what here!

Best,

Maria

Comment: There is no package called "Rtools". It is a separate program you have to install. You can get it from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. Or when it asked you inf you wanted to install the binary or build from source, just choose the binary. They the Rtools stuff isn't needed and it's much easier to install. You can force that option with `install.packages("tidytext", type="binary")` Make sure to do this in a fresh R session so you don't conflict with packages that are already loaded.

Comment: BTW, the stumbling point in this is in the top 10 lines: *"dependency ‘ISOcodes’ is not available"*. Because of that, the dependencies cascade. Get that installed and everything else should fall into place. (It should not require much, it is just data and help docs, no functions. [github](https://github.com/cran/ISOcodes))

Comment: @MrFlick I tried the type="binary" and it seemed to install fine now. However, when I use the library function the problem remains.
r2evans I installed ISOcodes, but the problem remains. 
Do you see anything I'm missing?

Comment: ```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(ISOcodes)
> install.packages("tidytext", type="binary")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
package ‘tidytext’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
Warning in install.packages :package ‘tidytext’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.4.4)
> library(tidytext)
Error in library(tidytext) : there is no package called ‘tidytext’
```

Comment: On. Is there any reason you are using such an old version of R? This would probably go away if you upgraded to at least `R 3.6.0`

Comment: @mrflick ah - it works now! Thanks a lot :)!

Answer (score 1):

@MrFlick posted the answer in the section above:

I had the old version of R. Installed to R 3.6.0 and everything works.
I first only updated Rstudio, not R itself. It wasn't until I updated R that it worked.

Find the link here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.6.0/